# Laravel how to check if at least one column value is true or false

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8

How can I check, if at least one of a bunch of checkboxes is checked/true? I'm using `Laravel 5.8`

My query right now:

```
$preferences = DB::table("preferences")
    ->select('day', 'evening', 'night', 'weekend', 'full_time', 'part_time')
    ->where(["user_id" => request()->user()->id])
    ->get();

return response(['success' => true, "preferences" => $preferences]);
```

So far this works, but "only" returns an array with each value. Like this:

```
[
  {
    day: 0,
    evening: 1,
    night: 0,
    weekend: 0,
    full_time: 1,
    part_time: 0
  }
]
```

I need some kind of value that tells me : `is-checked: true/false` - something like that.

How can I achieve this? Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: I dont know if I understood you correctly, if you want to filter items which are checked you can simply ```array_filter($result, function($item) { return $item == true });```. I could've mixed up the argument order

Comment: @TZiebura Yes, that was exactly what I was looking for! Jeez - so easy! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :)

```
array_filter($result, function($item) { return $item == true });
```

Comment: You don't need to supply a callback to the filter function when  you're just looking for truthy values - that is the default. "*If no callback is supplied, all entries of array equal to FALSE will be removed.*"

Answer (score 0):

try this on collection

```
$collection->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value == true;
});
```